# How do I update MS Access forms when I update the SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, forms, ms-access

Whenever I change my SQL Queries or add new columns to the existing tables, I need to create a new MS Access database connection to retrieve the new data.

As I am setting up forms in MS Access which need to update SQL Server, I would like also that when I change something in SQL Server it changes it to the existing connection in MS Access. I do drop the tables and recreate them, but when I hit refresh in MS Access, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

I did LINK the data, not imported it. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: you should use Link Table Manager to refresh the link tables

Comment: Thanks, worked !

Comment: You can do that by using VBA too, by calling `CurrentDb.TableDefs("MyTablename").RefreshLink`

Answer (score 0):

Under the External Data tab you should be doing an ODBC Database connection. Don't do the `Import the source data into a new table in the current database.` option. Do the other option `Link to the data source by creating a linked table`. By doing that it will automatically update your link whenever you get new fields in your SQL Server tables.